# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated EVEN with correct settings

Tags: php, linux, curl

I know this has been asked before, but I've followed all guides and somehow it still isn't working

I have both open_basedir set not to work on my domain and safe_mode off completely, heres phpinfo(); print out for the two

```
safe_mode   Off Off
open_basedir    /home/proagent/:/home/proagent:/tmp/:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/home/proagent/domains/xxx.com/bot::/home/proagent/domains/xxx.com/bot/   no value
```

But yet i'm still getting

Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in /home/proagent/domains/xxx.com/public_html/bot/scrape.php on line 58

Any ideas would be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) set, and your `phpinfo` output shows that you have it set (the left value counts), `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` will not work. Comment the line to allow access to all files, this is a `php.ini` example:

```
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.open-basedir
;open_basedir =
```